# On the Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am reading an article which has a fixed $S^1 \times I$ where $S^1$ is the unit circle and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ with coordinates $(\theta,t)$. Fix a Riemannian metric $$ds^2 = dt^2 + f(t)^2d\theta^2.$$It says that the Gauss curvature depends only on $t$ and is given by $$K(t) = -\frac{f''(t)}{f(t)}.$$

I can't reach this expression. I thought about using the curvature operator $$R : \mathfrak{X}(S^1 \times I) \times \mathfrak{X}(S^1 \times I) \times \Gamma(T\mathbb{R}^3\mid_{S^1 \times I}) \rightarrow \Gamma(T\mathbb{R}^3\mid_{S^1 \times I})$$ given by $$R(X,Y) = \nabla_X \nabla_Y - \nabla_Y\nabla_X - \nabla_{[X,Y]}.$$And the problem would reduce to finding the coordinate expression for the connection. Then I would use the formula of Gaussian curvature: $$K = \langle R(e_1,e_2)e_2,e_1\rangle.$$
But this means that we only need the Christoffel symbols to compute. Indeed, I computed and got $$\Gamma_{11}^1 = 0, \Gamma_{12}^1 = \Gamma_{21}^1 = f^3(t)f'(t), \ \Gamma_{22}^1 = 0,$$and $$\Gamma_{11}^2 = f(t)f'(t), \ \Gamma_{12}^2 = \Gamma_{21}^2 = \Gamma_{22}^2 = 0.$$But then, using the formula for the Gaussian curvature we see that $$R(\partial_\theta,\partial_t)\partial_t = 0.$$And this would imply that the Gaussian curvature is zero and it shouldn't according with the article. (Notice that it is known that the Gaussian curvature is zero in the cylinder...)

Thank you in advance.

`Edit:` I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347524/formula-for-gaussian-curvature-in-terms-of-unit-tangent-vector-fields?rq=1) which express the Gausian curvature for a warped product space in terms of the function associated. I see that this answers my question by making $u = t$ and $v = \theta$.

New question: How did the person that answered derive the $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$?

Comment: You can find various other posts that I've answered, as well, in which the calculations with moving frames are done. $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are the orthonormal coframe, so the metric is $\omega_1\otimes\omega_1+\omega_2\otimes\omega_2$. In this case $\omega_1=dt$ and $\omega_2=f(t)\,d\theta$. You can certainly do it with Christoffel symbols, but you have an error somewhere, as $\Gamma^1_{12}$ is most assuredly incorrect. There is no $\Bbb R^3$ in this picture, although you could picture this as the induced metric for a suitably defined surface of revolution.

Comment: You should show your calculations for the Christoffel symbols. How many times have you tried to recheck your calculations? It's not uncommon to have to redo these calculations from scratch (as if you'd never done it before) three or more times before you catch your error.

Comment: This cheat sheet by [Fred Akalin](https://www.akalin.com/curvature-moving-frames) sums up various calculation methods. The non-zero Christoffel symbols are
$$
\Gamma^1_{21}=\Gamma^1_{12}= \frac{\partial_t g_{\theta\theta}}{2g_{\theta\theta}}=\frac{2f(t)f'(t)}{2f^2(t)}=\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,,
$$
$$
\Gamma^1_{22}=-\frac{\partial_t g_{\theta\theta}}{2g_{tt}}=-\frac{2f(t)f'(t)}{2}=-f(t)f'(t)\,.
$$
You should sanity check this against the known Christoffel symbols of the flat metric in polar coordinates $ds^2=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2\,.$

Comment: I may have flipped the indices. $1$ stands for $t$ and $2$ for $\theta\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. nice thanks